# Show console window when debugging Win32 MFC application in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Here I have a MFC project. I want to see the console window also when I press F5. Then I can see the output.

Could I do some configuration in Project setting to enable this without changing the code?

Thanks.

[Solved]

- Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see Setting Visual C++ Project Properties.
- Click the Linker folder.
- Click the System property page.
- Modify the SubSystem property.

  Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VC6, the steps are similar:

Project->Settings

Select the Link tab

At the bottom in the Project Options text box, look for the /subsystem:windows setting.  Modify this to read /subsystem:console

Recompile, and now when you launch the application will launch with a console window.