# Using log4cxx with a Qt library

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008, log4j, log4cxx

Good afternoon guys,

I'm working on a project that is using a Qt library in Visual Studio 2008.  In this project I am using log4cxx 0.10.0 which is working fine.  However, I am unable to get it to display in (this projects) console.  I believe the reason has to do with it being a win32 application.

Anyone familiar with log4j(cxx) knows there is a properties file to configure.

Within that file, I have it writing to the console, but nothing is displayed.  The .cmd won't pop up like other programs I have written, and it will not display in the VS console like qDebug().

Any ideas on how to go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

`QDebug` is probably writing to the `stderr`, while `printf` or your log functions are connected only to `stdout`.

### Show the console in Visual Studio

You have two different ways to show the black console/terminal window from Visual Studio:

One: [Visual C++ Enable Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501968/visual-c-enable-console)

Add the following somewhere in your program before you start printing out to the console:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// ...

AllocConsole();
freopen("conin$","r",stdin);
freopen("conout$","w",stdout);
freopen("conout$","w",stderr);
// printf("Debugging Window:\n");
```

Or you can tell Visual Studio that you are writing a console program and to make one for you.

[Show console window when debugging Win32 MFC application in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545304/show-console-window-when-debugging-win32-mfc-application-in-vs2010)

Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > System > SubSystem

(This is the navigation to find the setting in VS 2010, it may be a little different for VS 2008)

Change from `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)` to `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`.

### Redirect `stderr` or `stdout`

Or a third option that you could try is to get your logging to print to the `stderr`, just like `QDebug`.

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/26852-stderr-vs-stdout.html

```
FILE *myerr = freopen("error.log", "wb", stderr);
```

Hope that helps.